Drag a group by clicking anywhere in that group (react-konva)
I am trying to drag a group containing a couple of elements. however, I cannot drag the group if I do not drag the elements inside it. I want to drag the group by clicking anywhere inside it.
This is the actual behavior of my code
This is the behavior I want to achieve
This is my code:
const ProductCustomizer = () => {

return (
    <Stage
          height={600}
          width={600}
          style={{ border: "3px solid black" }}
        >
          <Layer>
         <Group
          id={"group1"}
          opacity={1}
          draggable
        >
            <Image
                id={"img1"}
                x={50}
                y={50}
                width={50}
                height={50}
                opacity={1}
                rotation={1}
                image={"somelink"}
           />
           <Image
                id={"img2"}
                x={150}
                y={150}
                width={50}
                height={50}
                opacity={1}
                rotation={1}
                image={"someotherlink"}
           />
           </Group>
            <Transformer
              draggable
            />
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
)
}

I tried to add an invisible rectangle to the group and give it the same size and coords of the group to capture any drag events but did not work. I checked for the setPointerCapture() and hitFunc props but apparently the Group component does not have them.
BONUS: I can select multiple elements using a selection box (like the one in the first gif) and attach them to a transformer just like in the code. I obviously cannot drag the transformer and I get the same behavior as the first gif. Please tell me if there is a solution or if I should refactor my code and use smth else entirely.

You have added wrong link in 'This is the behavior I want to achieve'. Please modify it - So, we can check your requirement and help you out.

@MaulikPatel Thank you for pointing that out. I have uploaded the actual behavior gif now.

Thanks for updating your requirement. Sorry but Actually I am still unclear about your requirement. Are you able to drag that one picture from 1st image OR Do you need to select both the images (Same as gif 2) and then is it working ? Also, By this code We can't debug the issue, it will be great if you could share working code sample on codesandbox and give us that link. So, we can investigate issue.

@MaulikPatel Sure! Here is a reproducible example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-brepq9?file=src%2Fmain.tsx
